# Does the Advanced Warfare Center healing bonus stack with the bonus from HQ?

Tags: xcom-2

The Advanced Warfare Center is an Avenger facility that can be staffed with an engineer in order to increase the rate of healing for your injured soldiers (I think the healing rate is doubled?).

Scanning at your HQ can also increase the healing rate of your soldiers, if you purchase the scanning bonus at HQ.

Do these healing bonuses stack, or can you only receive the bonus of one while scanning at HQ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they stack for quadruple the recovery time and healing rate of your soldiers. But you'll need to keep an engineer staffed at the AWC at all times to have the 4x healing/recovery rate in effect, or it will drop back to 2x.

Comment: I just tested this out. The bonuses do seem to stack, but I'm not sure having both actually quadruples the healing rate, it seems to be only a small increase.

Comment: I mean, I had soldiers that were gravely injured that were out for 20 days, but back in less than a week, so I do think it 4x, however I'd like to see what others like you have gotten to confirm

Comment: I never had the med bonus at my HQ, but I had the building one, and that stacked with having engineers staffed while building for quadruple rate, so I expect this would the same way.

Comment: It's likely that it would double the base, rather than the total result, so 1/3 of the original time. Let's see if I can check.